# Transform data to xml from iframe

Tags: xml, html, iframe, bigdata

How can someone retrieve big data inside an iframe and transform the data to xml?

```
<html>
<iframe src = "http://demo.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/wfs?request=GetFeature&typenames=osm:polygon_barrier"></iframe
<html>
```

if you place the src value to the url bar you can see that the response is big data which are transforming to an xml.
Also due to the ammount of data sometimes i get the timeout error in the iframe which is not happening at the original page.

Comment: Is there a reason you're loading XML in an iframe? Surely your users aren't going to view it as-is.

Comment: Yes I am creating portal to many servers. and i want my users to view it as an xml as the browser is doing by default i suppose. If you place it to the url you will get a response of data which will later transorm automatically to an xml